# Defining custom permissions android

Tags: android, authentication, permissions

What would be the best strategy to define custom (application specific) permissions in Android?
I have an application of which part of it is accessible without requiring a login. But part of the application functionality is to be restricted to users who actually have logged in. I was trying to think of the best way to do this on Android and was thinking on the lines of defining a permission in the android manifest. But is this is the right tool for the job?
I come from a world where user permission are as easy as putting annotations on the class @admin, @manager. Nothing of that I suppose in the Android world.
Also my concern is I do not want the user to see my custom permissions while installing the app since it might just confuse/scare him for no reason.
Wanted to ask how people approach this issue? Do they just hardcode a utility method isLoggedIn() and call it before executing anything that requires permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain a cookie when a user logs in.  If that cookie is not set, I give them the un-authenticated experience.  If the cookie is set, I use it to make service calls.

Comment: thanks. when you say "cookie" does that mean you have session id returned from a webserver? I would be doing the same but I wish I could have a custom role like "loggedInUser" and then I could prevent some of my activites bieng accessed by another user by using some native android support on roles and permissions. But I think I am sounding too abstract now....thanks for your help though may be I don't know what I really want :)

Comment: yup, that is basically what I mean.  We store a little bit more than the session ID, but that is one of the points we store.  We have a CurrentUser object model, which maintains this cookie.  We also have an Enum class listing all possible actions.  When a user tries to perform a possible action, we call `mUser.canPerform(AppAction x)`, and if that returns true we change activities.